# Unable to make 'rake db:drop' work in development with Rails 5.1.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, pg

I'm no longer able to rake db:drop since I upgraded from Rails 4.2 to Rails 5.1.4.
I get the following error message whenever I try to run the task:

```
PG::ObjectInUse: ERROR:  database "myapp_development" is being 
accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There is 1 other session using the database.
: DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS "myapp_development"
Couldn't drop database 'myapp_development'
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ObjectInUse: ERROR:  database 
"myapp_development" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There is 1 other session using the database.
: DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS "myapp_development"
```

I used to make it work with this hack:
[Rails + Postgres drop error: database is being accessed by other users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369744/rails-postgres-drop-error-database-is-being-accessed-by-other-users)

Now, when I integrate this solution into my application, I get another error message:

```
FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
Couldn't drop database 'myapp_development'
rails aborted!
PG::AdminShutdown: FATAL:  terminating connection due to 
administrator command
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

Do you guys have a fix for this issue?
Btw, I'm running Postgres 9.6, ruby 2.4.2 and Rails 5.1.4.

Comment: I always receive this error when I actually access the database with another application at the same time. This is typically pgAdmin.

Comment: Do you have the rails server or console running?

Comment: Side note, but it's not advised to upgrade directly from `4.2.x` to `5.1.x`. You'll probably find it easier to upgrade to `5.0.x` first. Your question makes it sound like a new bug specific to `5.1.4`, but (if this is even a rails config error/bug at all!!) it could have been caused by *any* of the incremental versions in between.

Comment: @max I don't but even if I did, the script provided here allowed me to run the task. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369744/rails-postgres-drop-error-database-is-being-accessed-by-other-users

Comment: gem pgreset was the only thing that worked for me - ps, etc could find no such connection.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try to restart your DB, 
For postgres

> sudo service postgresql restart

then try 
rails db:drop / rake db:drop, maybe it will work

Answer (score 1):

To drop your database your database should not be accessed by any application.

This error tells that

1. you are using rails console which is using database  OR,
 2. you are using some tools tool postico,pgadmin, mysql workbench which is
    accessing database OR 
 3. you are using IDE like rubymine and accessing
    database via it OR 
 4. there is sidekiq or any other background job
    server running which accessing it.

**Solution**:
Before dropping database take care of following things
exit all rails console,
close database tools like mysql workbench,pgadmin
close database tabs in IDE 
stop sidekiq or any other background job

Answer (score 0):

**Why ?**

***database "myapp_development" is being accessed by other users*.**

You will get this error if your database is being opened either in console i.e *rails c* or *rails s* or any other mode.

**Solution**

1.Close console wherever you opened rails c or stop server if running

2.If you are unable to find console or server running i.e if everything closed still you are gettin error. Then try to close running process using below command

```
ps -au
```

This command will show all running processes.Just find keyword rails c/localhost/postgres.You can also filter processes using grep command like this

```
ps -au | grep 'rails c'
```

And kill the process using below command

`kill -9 PID_NUMBER`         // PID NUMBER you will find in second column when you run ps -au.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the database is being used by a user other than the one attempting to drop the table. The user attempting to drop the table is the one specified in `config/database.yml`

To see how that is, do:

```
za:myapp za$ cat config/database.yml | grep username
  #username: myapp
  # The password associated with the postgres role (username).
  username: myapp
```

Make sure that no other user is connected to the database while you are trying to drop it. In my case, another user "za" was connected to the database. I killed the session of that user and all went well.

```
za:myapp za$ rails db:drop
Dropped database 'myapp_development'
Dropped database 'myapp_test'
```

Back to work, create and then migrate:

```
za:myapp za$ rake db:create
za:myapp za$ rake db:migrate
RubyDep: WARNING: (To disable warnings, see:http://github.com/e2/ruby_dep/wiki/Disabling-warnings )
== 20180218181904 DeviseCreateUsers: migrating ================================
-- create_table(:users)
   -> 0.0286s
-- add_index(:users, :email, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0183s
-- add_index(:users, :reset_password_token, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0036s
== 20180218181904 DeviseCreateUsers: migrated (0.0507s) =======================
```