# Drop rails database on fly.io?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, fly

#### Question

How do I do a simple `rails db:drop` on fly.io?

#### Background

I tried

```bash
fly ssh console -C "/app/bin/rails db:drop DISABLE_DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_CHECK=1"
```

and also shelling in via

```bash
fly ssh myapp
```

then

```
/app/bin/rails db:drop DISABLE_DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_CHECK=1
```

but both give the same error:

```
# /app/bin/rails db:drop DISABLE_DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_CHECK=1 
D, [2022-12-03T07:19:04.077483 #564] DEBUG -- :    (5010.1ms)  DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS "myapp"
PG::ObjectInUse: ERROR:  database "myapp" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There is 1 other session using the database.
Couldn't drop database 'myapp'
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ObjectInUse: ERROR:  database "myapp" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There is 1 other session using the database.
```

#### Notes

- All browsers accessing the site are closed
- All shell sessions are ended
- I tried using [`ps -ef | grep postgres`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65738985/5783745) to get the process id in order to kill it, but all I see is `/bin/sh: 18: ps: not found`, and
- Related [thread](https://community.fly.io/t/how-can-i-drop-and-re-create-a-production-database-attached-to-my-app/2727).

#### Ideas

- It may be possible to [force postress to kill all connections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5408501/5783745) to allow the db:drop to succeed (although I haven't worked out how to do that yet)
- It may be possible to delete all the database tables (suggested [here](https://community.fly.io/t/stop-a-running-rails-server/8323/8))

Answer (score 0):

There's something else accessing your db, probably your web server.
You'll need to stop your web server, then you should be able to drop the db.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense, but how do you stop the rails server on fly.io?

Comment: hmm not really sure.

Comment: I actually remember that I tried to do a `db:reset` on heroku once and it wouldn't let me. I ended up opening the console and destroying all the records I had.

You could do it like that, or just write the destroy queries in your seed file, then run db:seed on fly and the records will go away.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll take the seeds route you suggest (it's a little tedious for a large db, but might be the only option available). Incidentally, it's super easy on heroku with one line `heroku pg:reset DATABASE --confirm myappname && heroku run rake db:migrate db:seed`