# Rails can't drop tables because of other containers using the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker

I have a problem. I have build an application in rails using docker. This application consists of 4 containers:

- Rails app
- Postgres DB
- Redis
- Sidekiq (Clone of rails app)

Now I want to reset my db in my rails app, but when I run:

```
docker-compose exec app rails db:migrate:reset
```

I get:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ObjectInUse: ERROR:  database "my_app_development" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There are 4 other sessions using the database.
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5750734/10673107) fix from someone, but this code results in:

```
kill: you need to specify whom to kill
```

I think because this is task will be executed in one container and it only looks for process within that container and not the other docker containers. My question is how I can reset my db without the other docker images to crash or anything, but temporary stop the database connections for them. I really need to be able to reset my database when I have to!

Please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to stop and reset everything, the easiest way is to ask Compose to stop all of the containers and delete all of the state

```bash
docker-compose down -v
```

then recreate the database

```bash
docker-compose run app rake db:create
```

and finally restart the application

```bash
docker-compose up -d
```

You might also be able to do this by stopping the application containers, running the reset command, and then restarting things

```bash
docker-compose stop app sidekiq
docker-compose run app rails db:migrate:reset
docker-compose up -d
```

One notable thing here is that I'm using `docker-compose run` and not `exec`.  This launches a new temporary container based on the `app` service, but overrides its `command:` with whatever you provide on the command line and doesn't publish `ports:`.  In particular your error suggests that you can't run this command while the main `rails server` is running; but if you stop it then there's not a running container you can `docker exec` into.  Starting a new container with `docker-compose run` gets around this problem; since it has the same network setup, image, and entrypoint wrapper as the main service, it should be able to run the same `rails` and `rake` commands.

Comment: I added `depends_on` to the rails app and added the other 3 containers. Does that conflict with this answer?

Comment: In my docker-compose.yml

Comment: The error message you quote implies to me that you can't run this particular command while any of the Ruby containers are still running.  A `depends_on:` declaration will help bring up smaller parts of the stack but doesn't affect the details of this answer at all.

Comment: Well, stopping sidekiq when it uses a `depends_on` closes the depending containers as well if I am correct?

Comment: I don't think that happens.  If both `app` and `sidekiq` declare `depends_on: [redis]` then in principle you couldn't stop `redis` until both depending containers are stopped, and I don't think Compose usually checks that.

Comment: To get what I want I use the `wait-for-it.sh` script for both containers and then wait for `db` and `redis`. I am still not sure about the depends_on... I feel it brings more disadvantages, when running a bigger network

Comment: `depends_on:` essentially does two things: if you `docker-compose up app` it ensures the database is started as well, and it mostly ensures the dependencies' DNS names will resolve (but not that the dependencies are actually running).  It's a little secondary to the question you're asking here.